# Routing with controllers in these html pages, is it possible?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I'm new in AngularJS development and I'm actually in front of a problem.
In my index.html I have already many scripts included like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/commons/language.js"></script>
```

And to be more clear, I would like to separate my app controllers from the app.js, like that:

```
home.js => HomeCtrl
about.js => AboutCtrl ..
```

But, of course, when I have started the routing, I had this error :

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/ng/areq?p0=homeCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

About my homeCtrl doesn't exist. 
So my question is, how can I specify that my controller js is included in home.html and not in index.html during the routing.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your controllers load first than the app in their own module. Your modules should reflect your directory structure for convinience.

```
// app/ctrl/main.js
angular.module('app.ctrl.main' []).controller('mainCtrl', function () {...});

// app/ctrl/about.js
angular.module('app.ctrl.about' []).controller('aboutCtrl', function () {...});
```

And load your app last making it dependent of the above modules:

```
// app/app.js
angular.module('app', ['app.ctrl.main', 'app.ctrl.about'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        // route configuration
    });
```

Your html should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/ctrl/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/ctrl/about.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the probleme is I will still many scripts included in my index.html file no ?

Comment: Oh, yeah. If that worries you, then go and find things to solve that. I've heard of requirejs being used along with angular. You can also concatenate and minify your files and have one file only (big, but one request only will be done).